# Does anyone have experience with polycaprolactone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, polymers

I am trying to create an emulsion from polycaprolactone. My efforts thus far have resulted in unstable emulsions which sediment and coalesce after some time. This is what I have tried:

Dissolve 5g of PCL in 100 mL of acetone.

Add the PCL solution drop by drop into a 1% Tween 80 solution agitated at 5000 rpm using a homogenizer.

Remove the solvent using a rotavap.